# If a subquery is used in both the SELECT and WHERE clause, is it executed more than once?

Tags: mysql

e.g. if I write

```
SELECT (subquery) FROM table WHERE (subquery)
```

Will `(subquery)` be executed more than once per row?

I'd alias it in the SELECT and use it in the WHERE, but that doesn't appear to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at the `EXPLAIN PLAN` of a very simple query that illustrate this use case.

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT (SELECT 1 FROM YOURTABLE LIMIT 1) 
 FROM DUAL 
 WHERE (SELECT 1 FROM YOURTABLE LIMIT 1);
```

Ignore the `LIMIT 1`, they are just there to avoid multiple rows error on my testing table.

The result-set will be

```
'1', 'PRIMARY', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'No tables used'
'3', 'SUBQUERY', 'YOURTABLE', 'index', NULL, 'PRIMARY', '4', NULL, '6', 'Using index'
'2', 'SUBQUERY', 'YOURTABLE', 'index', NULL, 'PRIMARY', '4', NULL, '6', 'Using index'
```

So as you can see, yes the sub-query will be executed two times.

If your subquery's value is to be used at multiple place, then you might consider using a `JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the answer is "yes".  Although the query optimizer is empowered to eliminate such common sub-expressions, query optimizers rarely do.

If you put the subquery in the `from` clause, it should only be executed once:

```
SELECT s.value
FROM table cross join
     (subquery) s
WHERE s.value
```

or, if you use a subquery:

```
SELECT value
FROM (SELECT (subquery) as value
      FROM table
     ) s
WHERE value <> 0;
```

In MySQL, this latter construct imposes the cost of materializing the subquery.  So, there is another MySQL extension that might make this more efficent:

```
SELECT (subquery) as value
FROM table 
HAVING value <> 0;
```

Comment: Didn't think to use `HAVING`. That's an easy fix and speeds up my query by about 20%. Thanks! The problem with joins is that you can't reference any other tables in the subquery, you have to move them outside to the ON which gets pretty ugly.